# How can I show download link on product page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I show download link on single product page.

This code is for get download link, but is not secure and is with path.

```
$downloads = $product->get_files();
foreach( $downloads as $key => $each_download ) {
    echo '<a href="'.$each_download["file"].'">Download</a>';
}
```

Now how can I get link exactly like woocommerce without path?

Comment: you want to print the url for only customers who purchased the product right?

Comment: @kashalo I want to get download link without path. example: (http://yoursite.com/?download_file=5957&order=wc_order_5b83fc22d40b0&email=bbb%40gmail.com&key=31dac8dc-f9e8-4dd1-a368-ed3e51c89c59)

Comment: alright i will  write the function for u but can you tell me where you want to display the link is there any specific hook you are using ?

Comment: On single product page, After " Add to cart " button.

Comment: alright i will write the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go :

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'download_products');

function download_products()
{

    $downloads = array();
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $downloads = wc_get_customer_available_downloads($user_id);
    if (!empty($downloads)) {
        foreach ($downloads as $download) {

            echo '<a href="' . $download['download_url'] . '">Download</a>';

        }
    }

}
```

**some explanation:**

What we have done here we used `wc_get_customer_available_downloads` function to check if the current user have any available downloads and if yes we loop through them and `echo` the url and with above code we will print all user purchased downloadable products link .

**now if you want to print only the current product download link you can use the following function:**

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'download_products');

function download_products()
{
    global $product;
    $downloads = array();
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $downloads = wc_get_customer_available_downloads($user_id);

    if (!empty($downloads)) {
        foreach ($downloads as $download) {
            if ($download['product_id'] === $product->get_id()) {
                echo '<a href="' . $download['download_url'] . '">Download</a>';
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a function that will get the id of that file instead of that filename, or even better a hash of that id.

Then that function will query the database and return the correct file.

So your link will end up like:

```
$downloads = $product->get_files();
foreach( $downloads as $key => $each_download ) {
    echo '<a href="http://example.net/function_name/method_for_download/'.$each_download["id"].'">Download</a>';
}
```