# How can I create shortcode for downloadable product links (woocommerce)?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, download

I use "barn2media woocommerce product table plugin" and I want to add shortcode for downloadable product link in custom field , for example: [downloadable_product_link] but if customer (who did not purchased the product) or visitor click download link, redirect an other page.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible, I also think that this script can do it.

```
add_shortcode('download_product',function($atts, $content){
        if(TEST_USER_CUSTOMER){
            extract(shortcode_atts(
                array(
                    'url' => URL_PRODUCT_FILE
                ), $atts));
        }else{
            $url = URL_PRODUCT_PAGE
        }
        return '<a href="'.$url.';">'.$content.'</a>';
    }
});
//[download_product url=MyProductURL]title[/download_product]
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I use the code in this link and I want to create a short code for the code that gives the download link here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52085845/12332001 @kashalo